# Object pointer in std::map getting corrupted when retrieved through getter

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, memory

I have a std::map of object pointers: `std::map<ConnectionID, IConnection *>`

It will only ever contain three entries where each derives from `IConnection *`, so I have made three convenience getters for retrieving each object, which casts the `IConnection *` entry to the correct object and returns it. It looks like this:

```
GameConnection * Client::GetGameConnection()
{
    GameConnection * pGameConn = NULL;
    if ((pGameConn = (GameConnection *)GetConnection(ConnectionID::GAME_CONNECTION)))
        return pGameConn;

    return nullptr;
}
```

The generic `GetConnection()` method looks like:

```
IConnection * Client::GetConnection(ConnectionID nConnID)
{
    auto result = m_connections.find(nConnID);

    if (result != m_connections.end())
    {
        return result->second;
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

I am *fairly* sure that `GetGameConnection` is the problem as it works if I retrieve the whole map and do:

```
std::map<ConnectionID, IConnection *> connections = pClient->GetConnections();
GameConnection * pGameConn = (GameConnection *)connections.at(ConnectionID::GAME_CONNECTION);
```

If it is the casting to `GameConnection *` that causes problems, how would one avoid doing this, and still be able to conveniently call GameConnection like `pClient->GetGameConnection()->FooBar();`?
The casting from `IConnection *` to `GameConnection *` should be okay though as it derives from that interface.

Comment: A map of "It will only ever contain three entries" sounds plain wrong

Comment: Doesn't the whole `GetGameConnection` method boil down to `return (GameConnection *)GetConnection(ConnectionID::GAME_CONNECTION);` ? Shouldn't it be a `dynamic_cast` instead of a C-style cast?

Comment: @DieterLücking It's a map because I iterate through it to check for incoming data. Thanks for your concern.
Laurent: You're right, I have corrected this.

Comment: Have you tried a `dynamic_cast` to make sure the `IConnection` is really a `GameConnection` and not `SomeOtherConnection`?

Comment: "getting corrupted" - how? as reported where? what should it be, and what is it really?

Comment: High level, I would suggest that you don't use a map for this. Have you considered three member pointers, or if you need iteration, an array with three entries? Low-level, the most likely cause for corruption would be an incorrect cast, which could be caused either by the map not containing the objects you expect, or the compiler doing the casting wrong (e.g. because it doesn't have the class definitions available). The solution to the latter is to use ´static_cast´ instead of a C-style cast.

Comment: @MarianSpanik I think that trying ```dynamic_cast``` lead me to the root of the problem. ```Client``` doesn't know about ```GameConnection``` as it only has a forward declaration and doesn't include the header. I am restructuring my includes now to see if this is indeed the problem. Almost entirely sure that it is.

Comment: @PeterJensen Rather than being relegated to helping reveal the problem, not using `dynamic_cast` probably _was_ the problem. IMO one should never, ever use C-style casts. As they boil down to 'try every other cast you can - **not** including `dynamic_cast` - until something _seems to_ work', which it often doesn't in reality - and they look stupendously ugly to boot. Seriously, why people cite ugliness against proper C++ casts is beyond me; they're clear and don't just blend into the background noise of all the other operators. And again more importantly: they express intent and check validity

Comment: @underscore_d I know that C++ casting has some benefits and are generally better, but I came from C -> C++ and I still do a lot of stuff the C-way. However, it seems that ```dynamic_cast``` revealed the true problem supporting your last statement: ."... and check validity".

Comment: @underscore_d Don't get me wrong. I am not shuffling includes around to continue using C-style casts. I am shuffling includes around so I can avoid the forward declarations. I don't actually use anything from each specific protocol, so I thought a forward declaration would suffice.

Comment: @PeterJensen [deleted to edit] Cool. Well, having been on receiving end of the next advice, I (still slightly flout it but) feel obliged to pass it on at least once: ;-) Rearranging declarations to make `static_cast` or a C-style fallback work, thanks to a now-visible inheritance chain, does 'work'. _But_ it's only reliably sustainable in cases where you _know_ that some other programmer - including your future self - isn't going to overlook it & shuffle things back, breaking everything horribly... which sadly are narrow cases! Ideally it's safer always to `dynamic_cast` & thus ensure validity

Comment: (of course, I was talking about polymorphism; I don't `dynamic_cast` for trivial situations)

Comment: @underscore_d I understand and agree. I need to get used to using more C++ features. You noticed the 'auto' keyword in my initial post? ;D C++ Not using old school casts would've probably saved me in the first place.
Latest comment: Yes, I know.

Comment: @MarianSpanik Would you mind throwing your comment in an answer, so that I can choose it as the answer?

Comment: @PeterJensen Heh, congrats on the `auto`! At least you're trying to go straight to C++11 or 14, rather than 03. I did a bit of 03 in the past and then lapsed. When I started again and C++11 was now a thing, the huge evolutionary step made me wonder how I ever put up with C++03 (or C ;-) `auto`, `std::initializer_list`, and lambdas - not in any particular order - just put it on a fundamentally different level.

Comment: @underscore_d People keep telling me to use C++11, though I think some of the features it offers hinder readability, such as the use of auto, actually. Trying to use it anyway.
True. C++ has a lot of great features to offer, but there really is so much that it will take some time for it all to sink in, and to get used to.

Comment: @PeterJensen `auto` is optional & not a point against C++11 - which includes far, far more - much of which I now can't imagine _not_ having. Besides, there are arguments on both sides for what "readability" means: is it having the type explicit, or is it having code be terse and not flowing into column 160 due to huge types? And sometimes it's just totally redundant: `someNamespace::SomeClass aClass = someNamespace::SomeClass::createInstance()`. Use it how much you want, not more! I hope your journey through C++ is as rewarding as mine has been. What else do you think might hinder readability?

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather recommend you using a

```
std::map<ConnectionID,std::shared_ptr<IConnection>> connections;
```

or at least

```
std::map<ConnectionID,std::weak_ptr<IConnection>> connections;
```

to make your life easier.

Comment: very good suggestion in general, but doesn't offer any explanation as to why this would help in this situation, and so only qualifies as a comment :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you populating m_connections map , properly ?.
because it can be case where there can be no value in map, and it will be giving back a nullPtr.

And the other case can be your pointer is getting expired or becoming dangling, so to prevent that use shared_ptr

```
std::map<ConnectionID,std::shared_ptr<IConnection>> connections;
```

Comment: No. There is no dangling pointers. The problem was that ```Client``` doesn't know about ```GameConnection``` aside from a forward declaration which obviously isn't enough to know that it derives from ```IConnection```. Thanks for the answer though.